# Cisco ASR Multiple BGP processes

Tags: cisco, bgp, vrf

Virtual Router: I have 1 ASR router that already has a multi-homed EBGP setup on AS#XXXXX, and I need an isolated BGP process that is also multi-homed (separate circuits) with a completely different AS#YYYYY, with complete route isolation (VRFs).  I've seen techniques such as per-vrf BGP router-id and local-as, replace-as.  My question is whether this is a safe technique for a long-term deployment.  I absolutely cannot have any bleed-over between the two AS#s.  They are treated as completely different entities.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

This would be a good fit for a VDC but looking it up I dont see the ASR supports VDCs, unless Im missing something.

VRFs are going to give you route table separation and should do the job quite well as long as you insure routes do not bleed between VRFs.

Since this is a virtual ASR could you not stand up a second and have it dedicated to the second AS?

Just a thought.